# How to access web.xml init parameters in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have stated my init parameter in `web.xml` and on accessing same in `init.jsp` I get output as `null`. I am using Tomcat-8

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>SecondWebProject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InitJsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/init.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>default_username</param-name>
            <param-value>default user</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InitJsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/init.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

MY init.jsp is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Init jsp</title>
 </head>
<body>
 Default username is: <%= config.getInitParameter("default_username") %>
<br>
 Default username is: <%=   
 getServletConfig().getInitParameter("default_username") %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

File structure within Eclipse is as:
 [image: file]

I am not able to find where I am doing wrong. Any help from your side will be valuable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please Make sure u put the  jsp at proper place/path.**

 I tested ur code(with tomcat7) & it is running fine, Only if i Put my jsp at correct path, path which is mentioned in **web.xml**

Check snapshot for reference, if place jsp directly under **WebContent/init.jsp ,it will run fine otherwise results null(check the url in snapshots which results null)**
[image]

Check the directory structure
[image: WebContent/init.jsp Correct path]
[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, but I have placed _init.jsp_ at correct place. I have added the screenshot of file structure in my question.

Comment: right click the jsp and run on server, n show the coming url

Comment: It is now working. I first cleaned and then stopped Tomcat; on restart it worked. I don't know what was the actual problem, but this trick worked. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Good!! I thought of saying that, but i was cross checking at my end , as it was not running fr u even aftr evrythng luks fine,